# Getting/Limiting N number of results for each unique value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, greatest-n-per-group

Is there an easy way of using the LIMIT clause to only pull the top N values for each different unique values? For example, if we have 30 different, numerical rows for each `A`, `B`, and `C`, how can we only pull up the first 5, 8, or N rows for each `A`, `B`, and `C`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem" and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You seems want :

```
select t.*
from table t
where pk in (select t1.pk 
             from table t1 
             where t.value = t1.value 
             order by t1.pk -- asc/desc 
             limit 5
            );
```

For latest version you can use `row_number()` function.